# unity get return as HTML page but not string from google apps script

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-apps-script

Unity===>

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class testScript : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(UpLoad());
    }

    IEnumerator UpLoad()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        
        form.AddField("name", "Jack");
        form.AddField("age", 100);

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://script.google.com....", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);
                Debug.Log("Up load Complete");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

google apps script==>

```
function doPost(e){
 
var param=e.parameter;
var name=param.name;
var age=param.age;
 
var replyMsg = 'Your name is：' + name + '，Age is：' + age; 
 
return ContentService.createTextOutput(replyMsg);
}
```

when I play the unity and get the `www.downloadHandler.text`, but appear the unity debug log as follows

錯誤body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}指令碼已完成，但未傳回任何值。

UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
NewBehaviourScript/d__1:MoveNext () (at Assets/NewBehaviourScript.cs:31)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)

*錯誤==>error
*指令碼已完成，但未傳回任何值==>The script was completed, but no value was returned

Comment: You would need to translate the whole error into english for us.

Comment: looks like a Log not like an error to me .... you get an HTML page as response .. not the text you expect

Comment: Yes, it's a URL return
many thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I deployed the GoogleSheet and get a new URL. After changing this in unity script, and it works!!